# Corona Screen Positioning issue

Tags: layout, position, screen, coronasdk

I have issue while working with corona screen positioning that the start `Y=0` of the content does not belong to top point on the screen, it resides rather a bit lower than expected,

I have listed different sample of current

[image]

Y values on the attached image. Here is my config code:

```
application =
{
    content =
    {
        width = 768,
        height = 1024,
        scale = "letterBox",
        fps = 60,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `letterbox` mode means you may have black bars on top and bottom or left and right side of the screen. That is why `(0, 0)` is not always positioned in top-left corner of the screen. Use ([display.screenOriginX](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/screenOriginX.html),[display.screenOriginY](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/screenOriginY.html)) 
as top-left point of the screen instead of `(0, 0)` to solve problem.

Read more about [Content Scaling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling).